# How exactly were the brothers tortured?

Tags: hyperdimension-neptunia

In *Hyperdimension Neptunia Re;Birth* after Vert reveals that the Brothers are in the torture room all we see is that they are playing games.

Sure the younger brother apparently hates the games that much but how is this torture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The games the Brother's were playing was BL games. BL is the acronym for *Boy's Love* which is *Shounen Ai/Yaoi*

> Yaoi (/ˈjaʊi/, Japanese: [ja.o.i]), also known as Boys' Love (BL), is a Japanese genre of fictional media focusing on romantic or sexual relationships between male characters, typically aimed at a female audience and usually created by female authors.

Source: [Wikipedia - Yaoi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yaoi)

The Brothers are Oppai Fanatics where in they idealize breasts to the point they

- they ignore "small chested" women unless they suddenly gorw much larger as is the case when Neptune enters HDD
- they would betray their Goddess, Blanc, and worship Vert because she has a much larger chest
- they would knowingly follow a fake Vert because she too has a large chest

Playing BL Games hit the Brothers in 2 weak points. firstly most men would be "flat chested" and BL games would have echii scenes of half naked men showing off their flat chests.

Secondly the Brothers are real ladies men as they did try and woo Compa and Vert in the beginning so seeing nothing but men would devoid them of women, particularly that it seems the older brother seemed to develop feeling that are more than familial to his younger bother